# Extracting Address' from police reports

Tags: c#, extract, geocoding

I'm currently working on a program that would be searching through medium-large strings and pulling out addresses so they can then be geocoded.

An example of what I had was:

```
private void cardCheck()            
{
    cardCount = mobjEntity.CardCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < cardCount; i++)
    {
        card = mobjEntity.Card[i];
        if (card.Text.Contains(" STREET ") || 
        card.Text.Contains(" Street") ||
        card.Text.Contains(" street") ||
        card.Text.Contains(" ST ") ||
        card.Text.Contains(" St ") ||
        card.Text.Contains(" st "))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not very good at regex and I was hoping one of you regex wiz' could show me a useful link for testing/learning regex.

I have written what I have above for every street type and it's very tedious and I still don't even know what to do from there.

This is an Ideal Input Output:

Input:
On Friday, April 9, 2010, at 9:45 a.m., I, Officer Janice Ruiz, was dispatched to 2170 Powell Street to investigate a burglary. I met with Frank Gaines, the homeowner who had reported the burglary.

Output:
2170 Powell Street

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input text.

Comment: I have, : On Friday, April 9, 2010, at 9:45 a.m., I, Officer Janice Ruiz, was dispatched to 2170 Powell Street to investigate a burglary. I met with Frank Gaines, the homeowner who had reported the burglary.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a regular expression to search the text?  A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regular%20expression%20for%20street%20address) returns several RE's that may work for you.  Here is one example:

```
\d{1,3}.?\d{0,3}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,30}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}
```

Here is a proof of concept: https://regex101.com/r/dH3jJ8/1

Comment: There are 30403 false negatives/positives with this I bet

Comment: I'll bet there are too.  But I did say this was an example, not a solution.